# 80s animated movie where a time traveller goes to the past and is mistaken for Jesus whilst surfing

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I need help finding an old animated movie I think was from the 80s.

I can only remember one scene off the top of my head, which was about the time traveller being in the past and going for a surf and the people who saw him thought he was Jesus as they thought he was walking on water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be *Go to Hell!!*, an Australian animated movie. It's from 1997, so a bit off your timeline, but the art is reminiscent of 80s animated movies.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0179829/):

> Based on the premise that "God" is actually an alien called G.D., who wiped out the dinosaurs and populated the Earth with apes from his own planet (who eventually evolve into us). "The Devil" is actually his son, "little Red", who disagrees with what he is doing and pops up throughout history trying to upset G.D.'s plans.

The whole movie is [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1cGYziG_3M), but needs to be logged in to be watched (age confirmation). Key timestamps, screenshots included:

- The surf scene happens starts from 51'10 ([Jesus goes for a surf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUhcp.png));
- Jesus is caught in a storm;
- a guy in a nearby fishing village spots him at 52'00, with the following dialogue, 
  [at the amazement of the townspeople](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJZR4.png):

  > Wow, look, a buddy's walking on water!
- Then Jesus is brought to land with a bunch of fishes, which appears to be a miracle.

Here's a trailer anyway:

---

Found with the Google query `animated movie time travel surf jesus site:imdb.com` which returned [the following review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2575344/?ref_=tt_urv):

> The Ark was not stolen, nor given to the people by God but actually built by the Israelites. **Surfing was not the reason that Jesus walked on water nor did he raise people from the dead because he used first aid.** This movie can be very offensive if not viewed with an open mind.